# Access a class method from a model in the Rakefile / Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rakefile

I have a model, let's call it Foobar.  I want to be able to run a cron job to update an attribute of all objects that are instances of Foobar.  So, in pseudocode, it might be something like this:

```
Foobar.all.each do |foobar|
  foobar.update_attributes({:my_attribute => 'updated'});
end
```

Now, let's say I wrap that in a class method called Foobar.run_update().

Calling Foobar.run_update() would work fine from the controller, or even from a view.  But, what I want to do is run run_update() from the Rakefile so that I can tie it into a cron run.  But, the Foobar class is not available to Rake when it is called from crontab.

How can I resolve that?  How can I access the class methods of Foobars from Rake, when Rake is called from cron?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: By rake you mean rake task right?

Comment: If you accept the highest voted answer you'll triple your reputation! :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load up the Rails environment by requiring **config/environment.rb**:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "production"
require '/where/your/rails/project/is/config/environment.rb'
```

Answer (score 11):

By rake, if you mean a rake task then adding `=> :environment` loads the rails environment for the task and you be able to call the `Foobar.run_update` method there. Like,

```
namespace :foobar do
  task :update => :environment do
    Foobar.run_update
  end
end
```

And you should just be able to call `rake foobar:update` from the console and have it scheduled as a cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

In my Sinatra apps I typically have the file `models/init.rb` which requires Sequel, sets up my DB connection, and then uses `require_relative` to require all my model files. My main application then does `require_relative "models/init"`.

With this setup any other script (including IRB) all I have to do is require the `models/init.rb` file myself, and I have full access to the same models and DB connection that the application has.